# Trigger a gradle task after ctrl-c ./gradlew bootRun

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, command-line

I'm trying to remove docker containers when `./gradlew bootRun` receives a ctrl-c exit in the terminal.

My bootRun configuration:

bootRun {

```
  systemProperties = System.properties
  dependsOn pathingJar
  doFirst {
    classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", pathingJar.archivePath)
  }
  ignoreExitValue true // what I was hoping would work
}
```

Task list:

```
$ ./gradlew bootrun -m
:compileJava SKIPPED
:generateGitProperties SKIPPED
:processResources SKIPPED
:classes SKIPPED
:composeUp SKIPPED
:findMainClass SKIPPED
:pathingJar SKIPPED
:bootRun SKIPPED
:composeDown SKIPPED
```

Was hoping that `ignoreExitValue` would cause gradle to move on to its next task when issuing a ctrl-c; however, this did not work.

How can I force gradle to run composeDown?

Comment: Have you tried `bootRun.finalizedBy(composeDown)`?